# Electron get payload of intercepted protocol

Tags: node.js, reactjs, electron

I use the [react-typescript-electron](https://github.com/electron-react-boilerplate/electron-react-boilerplate) boilerplate.

I want to intercept each HTTP call from the web app and handle some of them without sending them out to a server. According to the electron documentation, one should use [`protocol.handle`](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/protocol#protocolhandlescheme-handler), as the other methods (e.g., `protocol.interceptHttpProtocol`). Everything works fine for every HTTP method however, if I cannot access the body of the intercepted request.

I really don't know how can I retrieve the payload. I also tried to get it with `request.text()` and `request.body()`, but nothing is working.

Here is the snippet where I register the HTTP intercept:

app.whenReady()
.then(() => {
createWindow();

```
    // Add API
    protocol.handle('http', async (req) => {
        const { host, pathname } = new URL(req.url);

        if (pathname.substring(0, 5) === '/api/') {
            const r = await req;
            const json = await r.json(); // This fails

            console.log(`Api request intercepted ${host} + ${pathname}`);
            console.log(json);

            return new Response();
        }

        // This is needed for forwarding the index.html
        return net.fetch(req.url, {
            method: req.method,
            headers: req.headers,
            body: req.body,
            bypassCustomProtocolHandlers: true,
        });
    });

    app.on('activate', () => {
        // On macOS it's common to re-create a window in the app when the
        // dock icon is clicked and there are no other windows open.
        if (mainWindow === null) createWindow();
    });
})
.catch(console.log);
```